# Insert data into Postgresql using Python

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to `INSERT` values in a Postgresql TABLE. In my python code, there are two returned values `a` and `b` from different functions. a and b are `tuples`.

like,

```
a = ('cat', 'dog', 'tree')
b = ('city', 'town', 'road')
```

Database TABLE name is `description` with six columns. I am using

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO description VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)",(a + b))
```

I want to append the values within this table. But it is showing error, `Error syntax error at or near ","` Is there any other way or should I convert it to `list` from `tuple` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python doesn't have a (single) standard placeholder value for parameterized queries. SQLite uses `?`, but MySQL and Postgresql drivers use `%s` (for all data types, not just strings):

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO description VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (a + b))
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try using %s
>   as format specifier it would work.

Answer (score 0):

As *Blender* said it, you just do it with `%s` will be okay! but since you got some animal on your data, maybe you can use `pg` array to store those animal type on the same field!

```
create table description (a char(16), b char(16), c char(16), d char(16), e char(16), f char(16));
```

you can easy to store your data by:

INSERT INTO description VALUES('dog', 'cat', 'tree', 'city', 'town', 'road')

BUT, if your animals maybe incr, so the better way is `array`.

```
create table description2 (animals char(16)[], d char(16), e char(16), f char(16));
```

and put your data like this.

```
INSERT INTO description2 VALUES(ARRAY ['dog', 'cat', 'tree'], 'city', 'town', 'road');
```

and then you can easy to get your data by :

```
select * from description2;
```

`PG` is good database, have many `type` can be used!